# Filter zcard by last 30 days

Tags: redis

I am trying to know how many new followers a company have in last 30 days. Below what I have right now:

To add each new follower:

```
ts = time.time()
redis_store.zadd('followers_companies:'+str(company_id_to_fav), str(current_user.id), ts)
```

To retrieve all followers:

```
followers = redis_store.zcard('followers_companies:'+str(company.id))
```

So, how can I I filter `zcard` to retrieve only results from last 30 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to do this you need to use timestamp as score. It seems like you are using user ID as score (unless the SDK you're using has a different order for the options of [`ZADD`](https://redis.io/commands/zadd)).

Then, you can use [`ZRANGEBYSCORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) to retrieve only the last 30 days. You would use [`ZCOUNT`](https://redis.io/commands/zcount) if you only want to know how many, cardinality.

```
ts = time.time() - 30*day
redis_store.zcount('followers_companies:'+str(company_id_to_fav), ts, '+inf')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ZCOUNT](https://redis.io/commands/zcount) to get total number of elements between the min and max. In your case `max` will be `+inf` and `min` will be the timestamp value of 30 days ago.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD followers:1 1 a 2 b 5 c 25 d 45 e 65 f
(integer) 6
127.0.0.1:6379> ZCARD followers:1
(integer) 6
127.0.0.1:6379> ZCOUNT followers:1 35 inf
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE followers:1 35 inf
1) "e"
2) "f"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

For simplicity i assumed 65 if the current timestamp and 35 is the 30 days ago. You may validate it with `ZRANGEBYSCORE`.